# Confidence Intervals for strongly mixing stochastic processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

I have $s(t)$, a stationary stochastic process that we know is strongly mixing - and I also know that samples from $s(t)$ are definitely correlated over time. I want to estimate the mean of $s(t)$, $\mathbb{E}[s(t)]$. Since strong mixing implies ergodicity, I can simply calculate sample means to find $\mathbb{E}[s(t)]$.

Does anyone know how I can go about estimating empirical variance so I can get confidence intervals for the estimated mean?

If $s(t)$ was Markovian, for example, I could use the Strong Markov Property to find empirical variance, but I have no clue how to do this for my general, non-Markovian $s(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

See e.g. [Confidence interval estimation of the mean of stationary stochastic processes: A comparison of batch means and weighted batch means approach](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236111526_Confidence_interval_estimation_of_the_mean_of_stationary_stochastic_processes_A_comparison_of_batch_means_and_weighted_batch_means_approach?enrichId=rgreq-3421a9c1ef72c04de8129f1dfaa86784-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzIzNjExMTUyNjtBUzoxMDMyODA0ODI5Nzk4NDNAMTQwMTYzNTM5NDIxNg%3D%3D&el=1_x_3&_esc=publicationCoverPdf) and [Using standardized time series to estimate confidence intervals for the difference between two stationary stochastic processes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/170544?seq=1)
and references therein.